# KD-tree execution time

Tags: python

I am working on building a kd-tree to process a list of 3D points (tuples). The tree branches left or depending on the median value in the point list. The median value is calculated by sorting the points and returning the index of the middle point. As for kd-trees this can be the x, y or z value depending on the depth of the tree (ie axis = depth % k).

The median value is added to each node and data (ie the points) is only added to the node once a predetermined length of list containing the points is reached. So only the leaf nodes contain data.

Below is a table for the running times (seconds)

[image]

My question is: I was wondering why there is a blow out on time for the tree build once 10,000,000 points are processed. Is this due to hardware or possibly the sorting function? Any help on reducing processing time for a large amount of points would be appreciated.

Code below:

```
from operator import itemgetter
import time

def main():
    time_start_r = time.clock()
    points = random_points(10000)
    time_finish_r = time.clock()
    print "random run time = " + str(time_finish_r - time_start_r) + " sec"

    time_start_t = time.clock()
    k = len(points[0]) 
    kd = KDTree()
    kd.build_tree(points, 0, k)
    time_finish_t = time.clock()
    print "tree build = " + str(time_finish_t - time_start_t) + " sec"   

    time_start_l = time.clock()
    print kd.getLeafCount(kd.root)
    time_finish_l = time.clock()
    print "leaf count = " + str(time_finish_l - time_start_l) + " sec"

    time_start_d = time.clock()
    count = kd.getDepth(kd.root, 0)
    time_finish_d = time.clock()
    print "find depth = " + str(time_finish_d - time_start_d) + " sec"
    print count

def random_points(n):
    points = []
    for i in range(n):
        x = round(100 * random.random(), 4)
        y = round(100 * random.random(), 4)
        z = round(100 * random.random(), 4)
        points.append((x ,y, z))
    return points

def median_index(points, axis):
    points = sorted(points, key=itemgetter(axis))

    return len(points) / 2

class Node:

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.points = None

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

class KDTree:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def build_tree(self, points, depth, k):
        axis = depth % k
        i = median_index(points, axis)
        #print points
        node = Node()
        if self.root == None:
            self.root = node
            node.value = points[i][axis] #median value for x, y or z
        if len(points) <= 20:
            node = Node()
            node.points = points
            return node
        else:
            node.value = points[i][axis]
            node.left = self.build_tree(points[:i], depth + 1, k)
            node.right = self.build_tree(points[i:], depth + 1, k)   
        return node

    def inorder(self, node):
        if node == None:
            return
        else:
            self.inorder(node.left)
            if node.points is not None:
                print node.points
            #print node.value
            self.inorder(node.right)
    def getDepth(self, node, count):
        if node == None:
            return 0
    if (node.left is None and node.right is None):
        return count          
    else:
        return self.getDepth(node.left, count + 1)

    def getLeafCount(self, node):
        if node is None:
            return 0
        if(node.left is None and node.right is None):
            return 1
        else:
            return self.getLeafCount(node.left) + self.getLeafCount(node.right)       

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Define ```blow out```. The step from 1M->10M does not look worse to me than the one from 10k->100k for example. While for the small ones, memory-hierarchies maybe play a role, i'm somewhat scared by constants in the code like ```if len(points) <= 20:```. I would not be surprised that different problems / sizes lead to very different statistics and a very different build_tree path. (but to be honest: i never got into the internals of these trees and i might just be wrong). Is this a learning-experience or why don't you stick to scipy or sklearn?

Comment: I just would have have thought python sort was O(nlogn) and insert into a KD-tree was O(logn) so by my understanding this would be O(logn + logn) I could be mistaken. When plotting these times it looks more like O(n^2). Possibly I am interpreting the graph wrong? The if len(points) <= 20 is to limit the minimum size of the final lists.

Comment: Eventually I will do statistics on each bin and too few elements in each bin would effect the statistics. The final code will have this passed as a parameter. It is partly learning and partly for smoothing gps data to use in generating a digital elevation model.  I have looked at sklearn but wasn't sure if it would do the specific job I required. Thanks for your reply